# Making volley calls when app is in background

Tags: android, android-volley, background-application

I want to make volley calls when the app is in the background: what is the best way?

I mean is it safe to just call addToRequestQueue() directly or it has to be called through service

MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [GoogleSyncFramework](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) for background data syncing/fetching.

You can use background syncing and you can use volley for request. For your case calling it in background `MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);` is safe.